# How to select the first and last occurring <td> in a <tr>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a html table which has a structure like :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <input type="hidden" name="a" value="x">
         <input type="hidden" name="b" value="y">
         <td>First Cell</td>
         <td>Some text</td>
         <td>Some text</td>
         <td>Last Cell</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What i want is a generic way using CSS to always select the first and last occurring  of each row as the number of hidden input element may differ with each instance.
PS: What I am trying to do is that in my application i want to remove the left-border from the first 's and right-border from the last 's from all the existing tables using a common css. The overall structure remains the same but the number of hidden input fields and cells may differ.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Learner Good to know that..Thanks!..  I already got the structure like this only. For now may be i can use the jquery to find the first and last <td>.

Comment: yes you can use jquery to do. see my answer it may be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate multiple CSS selectors with a comma:

```
td:first-child, td:last-child { background: red; }
```

By the way, check your markup as it looks invalid (`input` element inside `tr` is not allowed).

Comment: perfect answer. @newbie maybe you can read this page http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/ selectors are really usefull!

Comment: Actually the problem was that input tag only..I am not able to use these selectors because of those.. Thanks for highlighting that it is invalid HTML..I already got the structure like that only..I will make the necessary changes..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have keywords for that predefined in jquery

> See reference **[:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** and **[:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)**

To get first `td`

```
 $("tr").find("td:first").html();
```

To get last `td`

```
      $("tr").find("td:last").html();
```

this works and its easy

NOTE : dont put html content directly into a `tr` always use `td` to do so.

> ex :

```
 <tr>
    <td> <input type="hidden" name="a" value="x"> </td>
    <td> <input type="hidden" name="b" value="y"> </td>
 </tr>
```